# Spearman correlation with heatmap between 2 columns with different dataset in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, seaborn, heatmap, correlation

I would like to seek support pertaining to the **Spearman** correlation matrix for 2 different dataset and generating it to a heatmap.

Listed below is the sample data:

| Expression | PR | Metrics |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Engagement | 0.33 | 0.70 |
| Excitement | 0.33 | 0.15 |
| Focus | 0.33 | 0.36 |
| Interest | 0.67 | 0.47 |
| Relaxation | 0.55 | 0.20 |
| Stress | 0.44 | 0.40 |

As these data are not imported from a csv file (Due to the need for modification in future), it is created via a df. And the values are converted to float using **astype(float)**

The way that I have created the df and converting the types are provided here.

```
data = {
    'Expression':['Engagement', 'Excitement', 'Focus','Interest','Relaxation','Stress'],
    'PR': ['0.33','0.33','0.33','0.67','0.55','0.44'],
    'Metrics': ['0.70','0.15','0.36','0.47','0.20','0.40']
    }

df['PR']=df['PR'].astype(float) #Converts object dtype to float
df['Metrics']=df['Metrics'].astype(float) #Converts object dtype to float
```

After which, if I were to use `df.corr()`, it will only provide the correlation result as shown:

```
                      PR        Metrics
PR              1.000000       -0.048189
Metrics        -0.048189        1.000000
```

However, what I would like to generate is a **Spearman** correlation matrix that shows the correlation between **EACH** expression from the PR and Metrics, as to what is provided in the snipped image, inclusive of the axes title of **Metrics** and **PR** either in the X or Y axes.

[image]

How should I go about it in this case then?

Comment: You don't seem to have enough data to calculate such a correlation. You'd need multiple observations for each type of expression.  Note how your input data only has 12 values, while your matrix needs to calculate aggregate information for 36 values.

Comment: @JohanC Thanks for the response, in this case, would it be correct not to use the computed mean? the data provided above (12 values) comes from the computed mean.

If I'm not supposed to use the computed means, then I would have the following:
PR: 3 sets of 6 Values (3tester)
Metrics: A - 15 sets, B - 21 sets, C - 18 sets (all are of 6 data).

Otherwise, how should I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

You need at least two different measurements to be able to calculate a correlation.

The following example supposes the `PR` and `Metrics` are organized as two matching dataframes with the expressions as index and one columns for each observation.  `np.corrcoef(df_pr, df_metr)` will calculate the correlation between each of the rows in both datasets, resulting in a 12x12 matrix. The left upper quarter are the correlations between each of the rows of `df_pr`. The right upper quarter are the correlations between the rows of `df_pr` with the rows of `df_metr`.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

expressions = ['Engagement', 'Excitement', 'Focus', 'Interest', 'Relaxation', 'Stress']
N = len(expressions)
np.random.seed(20230329)
df_pr = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(N, 4).round(3), index=expressions)
df_metr = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(N, 4).round(2), index=expressions)
corr_matrix = np.corrcoef(df_pr, df_metr)[:N, N:]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(9, 8))
ax = sns.heatmap(corr_matrix, xticklabels=df_metr.index, yticklabels=df_pr.index,
                 annot=True, cmap='RdYlGn', vmin=-1, vmax=1)
ax.set_xlabel('Metrics')
ax.set_ylabel('PR')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: correlation heatmap between two sets]

PS: This is how the test for `df_pr` looks like:

```
                0      1      2      3
Engagement  0.908  0.966  0.448  0.497
Excitement  0.335  0.609  0.287  0.983
Focus       0.235  0.989  0.323  0.077
Interest    0.219  0.197  0.945  0.887
Relaxation  0.453  0.479  0.921  0.662
Stress      0.767  0.618  0.037  0.597
```

And `df_metr`:

```
               0     1     2     3
Engagement  0.21  0.45  0.76  0.27
Excitement  0.12  0.21  0.49  0.46
Focus       0.06  0.82  0.79  0.34
Interest    0.13  0.87  0.14  0.81
Relaxation  0.74  0.43  0.48  0.77
Stress      0.22  0.87  0.82  0.51
```

Comment: thanks for the response. In this case, if the number of sets of data against Metrics and PR are different, would it cause any complication?

ie: PR consists of 3sets of data (since they are survey responses), while the Metrics (Recorded data during experiment) consists of the following: A - 15sets, B - 21 sets, C - 18sets.

Comment: You don't have enough information for a correlation matrix. Maybe you could compare the mean of both via a bar plot? E.g. `pd.read_html('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75864604')[0].set_index('Expression').plot.bar()`

Comment: Alright, Much appreciated!